# Increase the speed of Countdown Timer

Tags: vba, powerpoint

```
Sub countdown()

Dim time As Date
time = Now()
time = DateAdd("s", 30, time)

Do Until time < Now()
DoEvents
oSh.TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "ss")
Loop
        
End Sub
```

I am able to create a 30 second countdown timer using the above code. **Is there a way to completely show the countdown timer in 15 seconds?** Can we go through all the numbers from 30 to 0 in 15 seconds instead of 30 seconds; i.e showing 2 numbers in 1 second.

### Updated Code:

```vb
Sub countdown()

'set the range of the countdown timer
CounterStart = 400
CounterEnd = 100

Dim N1 As Single
N1 = Timer + CounterStart

Do Until N1 < Timer()
DoEvents
oSh.TextFrame.TextRange = ((N1 - (Timer)) + 1)
If oSh.TextFrame.TextRange = CounterEnd Then Exit Sub
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, that `Now` increments in full seconds, so you have to user `Timer` to obtain split seconds:

```vb
Sub countdown()

    Dim StopTime    As Date
    
    StopTime = DateAdd("s", 15, Now)

    Do
        oSh.TextFrame.TextRange = Second(CDate(2 * (StopTime - (Date + Timer / 86400))))
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Now >= StopTime
        
End Sub
```

Comment: This will show 1,2,3,...,15 in 15 seconds. I would like to show 1,2,3,...,30 in 15 seconds.

Comment: This works! I was trying to make a countdown of 100 seconds. Instead of it showing up as "1:40...", I managed to make it show "100..." by using the updated code. In that case, how would we go about increasing the speed of the countdown timer? Multiplying it by 2 didn't change the interval. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: `15` is the interval. `2` is the display update speed factor. The product of these must be 60 or less, or another method will be required.